Identify this movie where seprated couple get back together and go to the flea market again
A movie made after 1990. 
The only thing I can remember is that this is the story of a couple who, at some point of the story, buy an object at a flea market or so. Then they break out, get back together and go to the flea market again. In my memory it might be raining the second time, but I am not sure of that. 
Until recently I thought it was "the eternal sunshine of the spotless mind" so there must be some similitude. 
I know this is very vague but I really have nothing else.

This description calls to mind War of the Roses with Michael Douglas, Kathleen Turner, and Danny Devito, who plays a lawyer friend to both, and the narrator of the movie. The movie is a tale of the degredation of their marriage. They spontaneously meet at an auction where she outbids him for a small figurine he wants to add to his collection. The figurine plays a very impaortant part in the later scenes devoted to how the "war" between them is carried out. I especially remember the rain scene - they are on Martha's Vineyard? (that location could be wrong, but it was an island - IMDB show the filming locations include Whidbey Island, WA, which could serve as that stand-in), and have to run through the rain to catch the ferry after the auction.

Thank you very much. I don't know how you managed to think about this movie since my description is almost completely wrong! My memory must have merged the two movies somehow. Nevertheless the scene at the auction is the one I am thinking of. It takes place in Nantucket BTW.
